# How to set path for image in any system to get image

Tags: java

enter

```
    try {
        Image in = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("C:\\User\\test\\1.jpg");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(in)), "YOur Requested Image", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(in.getWidth(null), in.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = out.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(in, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        ImageIO.write(out, "jpg", new File("C:\\User\\test\\Test01.jpg"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here the directory is my problem when I run this program to my lap its says file does not exit I am change directory and run correctly but when ever I change in to pc or lap its ask its directory how to slove it single code to run every pc or lap

Comment: You can pass the value for your path from some configuration file.

Comment: One possible solution might be to use `System.getProperty("user.home")` which returns the current user's home directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, like with any platform/install specific work in a platform independent language such as Java, you'll need to do some horrible *hacky stuff* (see below) if you want to continue down the hard coded, absolute path route.
If you insist on having an absolute path you could specify a config file that is OS/intall specific for each install like others have mentioned.

Really, in a well designed application you wont need to specify absolute addresses to resources (such as images).  Any images your application needs would be in your class-path, or referenced from a fixed point (such as `user.home`) and only relative (`./images/Test001.jpg`) paths would be required.

**The Hacky (*not recommended*) Stuff**

You could build the path from getting a list of roots with File.[listRoots()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots%28%29), in Linux/Unix there will be only one (`/`), in Windows you'll need to decide which drive to use.  Then instead of hard coded file seperators (`\` on Linux/Unix, `/` on Windows, etc), get the OS specific File.[seperator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator).

i.e.

```
String file = File.listRoots()[0] +           //First root found
              File.seperator + "User" +       
              File.seperator + "Test" +       //This directory is easier to access with System.getProperty("user.home") though
              File.seperator + "Test01.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either keep the path configurable or add the location to classpath and use [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to load the file

Answer (score 0):

You can create properties file on your pc and on your lap. Each of them will contain proper value for path to your file. Then in code you can do:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {
    input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
    prop.load(input);

    String path = prop.getProperty("yourpath");

    // your code with reading and writing to files here

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```